# rotate and position divs

Tags: css, position

I am trying to figure out a solution to position my rotated divs as shown in the attached pics. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

[image]

Comment: http://www.css3files.com/transform/

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#diamond

Comment: This question shows no research effort

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `position:absolute` and figuring out the appropriate left/top coordinates to produce the desired result? I find that adjusting the transform-origin can make things a bit easier, you can read more about that at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp.

Comment: What I have done is set the blue element to position relative. I I wrapped my rotated divs in a wrapper and set it to absolute so I can position them all within the blue container. The way I understand how absolute positioning works is there must be a container with a relative position in-order for absolute positioning to work. This poses a problem because I set my wrapper to absolute.. So yes I had thought of absolute positioning, but uncertain how to apply it in this circumstance.

Comment: You're assumption is incorrect, setting `position:absolute` on an element that's inside a container with `position:absolute` will behave as expected (positioned relative to the container not the document). Is it not working in your example? If not, something else may be the culprit. If you post you code here or share it using JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) I'd be happy to take a look.